# Creating an "anti-botting" system by adding values into the database

Tags: php, database

I have no clue on how to make this to work, so I'm just looking for ideas currently, let me explain what I want to make;
Let's say I have a button named "click".
Everytime I press this button, it adds 1 to the database, so when I have pressed it 10 times, it holds the value "10" in the database column named "clicks". This is already made though.
I just need something that can check how fast I was pressing the button the 10 times to make an anti botting system. So I thought that making a column in the database named "time" this "time" column resets itself every 10 seconds and adds 1 to the column everytime the "click" button is pressed. Then I can make something in my PHP script like this:
If time > 200 DELETE USER etc.

So if a someone should be able to get the "time" column on 200 before it resets itself, it must be a bot pressing since it is not human-like to press that many times in only 10 seconds.

I have read something about TIMESTAMP and INTERVAL but I cannot get it to woth the way I thought. I simply just need a column that will delete all data inside it, after a certain time.

Any suggestions are welcome! 
Thanks in advance.

I've come this far with the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['djahff'])) { // The button
require_once('connectvars.php'); // The DB connection
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    $idsession = $_SESSION['id'];
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO pbclickslogin SET cps=1, id='$idsession' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cps=cps+1"); // Adding 1 to the column "cps" where username=$username

    $data = mysql_query("SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), mark) > 10 FROM pbclickslogin WHERE username='$username'") // Checking if the difference from mark and now is 10 seconds I assume?
    or die(mysql_error());
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, "UPDATE pbclickslogin SET cps='0', mark=NOW() WHERE username='$username'"); // Updating cps and mark because the difference from mark and now was 10 seconds.
 }
}
```

The site updates everytime the button is pressed, it's a button made with input type "submit".

Uhmm I didn't really understand you fully Algomorph but I assume it was because of my code posting mistakes. Sorry I am still new on this forum. Anyway I guess I have an update statement here etc.? Are there still the same problems as you mentioned before?

Ps. Thanks for noticing me about the forum format

I have now added a little more code:

```
if ($info[0] == 1) {
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, "UPDATE pbclickslogin SET cps='0', mark=NOW() WHERE username='$username'"); // Updating cps and mark because the difference from mark and now was 10 seconds.
}
```

The code however, never Update now. I tried with ($info['0'] == 1) aswell but with no luck unfortunatly. Besides that I don't really understand this now, what is $info[0]? Is it finding something inside the database that is 0 or something? I usually only use $info when calling on columns. Thanks again man :)

Another few changes were added, the code we've got now is as followed:

```
if (isset($_POST['djahff'])) { // The button

require_once('connectvars.php'); // The DB connection
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    $idsession = $_SESSION['id'];
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO pbclickslogin SET cps=1, id='$idsession' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cps=cps+1"); // Adding 1 to the column "cps" where username=$username

    $data = mysql_query("SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, mark, NOW() ) > 10 FROM pbclickslogin WHERE id='$idsession';") // Checking if the difference from mark and now is 10 seconds I assume?
    or die(mysql_error());
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {
if ($info[0] == 1) {
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, "UPDATE pbclickslogin SET cps='0', mark=NOW() WHERE id='$idsession'"); // Updating cps and mark because the difference from mark and now was 10 seconds.
}
 }
}
```

to Algomorph: Why did you change NOW() ) > 10 to NOW() ) > 1000 by the way? 
Plus: The problem I am having at the moment is that when I press the button "djahff" it updates the timestamp "mark" but not the integer "cps".

Thanks :-) - We're getting closer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which DBMS you're using, but you could do exactly what you described the following way. Make two columns:

- integer [clicks]
- timestamp [mark]

When the user clicks, check [mark] and compare it to current date & time. If there is a more than 10 second difference, set [clicks] to 1 and mark to the current date & time (NOW() function in mysql, current_timestamp() function in PostgreSQL).

Otherwise, check [clicks]. If it exceeds 200, kick the user out. Otherwise, increment it by one.

Comment: O yeah this is exactly what I need. I use MYSQL, phpMyAdmin. This all sounds like a great idea but how would I compare the timestamp set when the user clicks with the time 10 seconds after the user clicks? Wont the "timestamp" reset itself when the user clicks again?

Comment: With MySQL, you can do it with: SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,NOW(),(SELECT mark FROM myTable WHERE ...)) > 10. This will produce "1" if the stored timestamp is older than 10 seconds, 0 otherwise.

Comment: P.S. don't update the [mark] if it isn't older than 10 seconds, so it won't "reset."

Comment: I still don't understand how I can avoid resetting it when the "mark" is set once you press the click button. It will update both "clicks" and "mark" right? And what is supposed to stay at: "FROM myTable WHERE ...))" at the dots?

Comment: Okay. I'm assuming that you want click-counts for different users to be logged separately, so make another column in your table identify the user, i.e. by IP address or some kind of unique session id you can get from the client through PHP. That's what goes in the WHERE clause. In your PHP code, first run the check query, i.e. SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,NOW(),mark) > 10 FROM myTable WHERE sessionId = 'some IP', see what that returns. If it returns 1/true, run an UPDATE statement with the same WHERE clause that resets [clicks] to 1 and [mark] to NOW(). Otherwise, query if [clicks]>200, etc.

Comment: Hmmm okay man thanks very much, I have the whole day to try and make this to work today so I might be able to find out doing this by tonight :) - I'll return if I run into troubles I cannot explain and hope you can answer them. Thanks for your patience so far

Comment: I have written a code that I have made so far, I only have one problem  that I can still not understand, maybe you can help me? I used "mark" as timestamp and cps as "clicks"

Comment: I see now. Your code is fine, except for this:
you need to check if $info[0] == 1 and only do the UPDATE then. And you don't really need the while loop if ids are unique, you'll get one row exactly.

Comment: I tried adding $info[0] == 1 in my while loop. However I could still not get it to work. It simply do not update the "cps" it keeps going up and does not reset every 10 seconds. A problem though is that "mark" is still updating everytime the button "djahff" is pressed. Any other ideas?

ps. I will try and remove the "while loops" once I get this to work :)

Comment: $info is the array which has one row from the table returned by your query. You get that table in the $result variable, then you're using mysql_fetch_array to get an array that represents one row from this table. In this case, the table has only one cell (one row and one column), which can take on the values 1 or 0, so $info[0] should give you this value.
See what values it produces by printing $indo[0] somewhere in your html. I'm going to try to test your code (need to get PHP & mysql set up on my home machine)

Comment: I just noticed, why are you using $idsession in the insert, but then checking the $username? Shouldn't " id='$idsession'" be in the WHERE clause instead?

Comment: Also - this time my mistake, I think I reversed the order of parameters in the TIMESTAMPDIFF functions. Try SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, mark, NOW() ) > 1000 FROM pbclickslogin WHERE id='$idsession';

Comment: O man, thanks a lot. I have a lot to try once I get home from school I see. I don't think using id or username would make any difference since both of them are unique? but I can try if you believe it could make a difference. :) I am home in 5 hours and then I'll try it.

Comment: btw I added some more if you did not notice :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19177/discussion-between-algomorph-and-peterrr)

Answer (score 1):

if (isset($_POST['djahff'])) { // The button

```
require_once('connectvars.php'); // The DB connection
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    $idsession = $_SESSION['id'];
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO pbclickslogin SET cps=1,       id='$idsession' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cps=cps+1"); // Adding 1 to the column "cps" where username=$username

    $data = mysql_query("SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), mark) > 10 FROM pbclickslogin WHERE username='$username'") // Checking if the difference from mark and now is 10 seconds I assume?
    or die(mysql_error());
```

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, "UPDATE pbclickslogin SET cps='1', mark=NOW() WHERE username='$username'"); // Updating cps and mark because the difference from mark and now was 10 seconds.
 }
}

Here is the code that I understanded from what Algomorph told me about. The problem is just that the user clicks on the button "djahff" a lot times past these 10 seconds. And everytime the button is pressed, the "mark" column updates back to what the time is now.

Besides that everytime works fine :) Any suggestions?
@Algomorph

- Peter

Comment: There are multiple problems with the code. (1) the insert statement should happen when you get a new user/session and set the clicks to 0, not 1. (2) I see your checking code but I don't see your UPDATE code at all. Whatever value you store in the mark column cannot be changed unless you run an UPDATE on that row. It does not "reset". (3) Where is the code that checks the value of [cps] ? (4) Please follow the forum's format and move this as a part of your question.

Comment: Oh yes I see sorry - I have editted my question and added some new code. I don't know if you missed some of the code? I use the "UPDATE" SQL statement but I don't know if it's used wrong?

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. 
Sorry to get back to you so late, apparently stackoverflow doesn't send email notifications about chat responses. Could you go back to the forum and mark my response below as the solution?